# DateTime adding up in C#

Tags: c#

I have an excel sheet which has time in one of it's columns.

Example:

```
Name, Time
John  02:32
Peter 14:20
Paul  11:00
```

I imported my excel to a datagrid view, and I want to total up the time.
I don't know how to add up the time.

I did try the DateTime but it doesn't work, maybe I missed something.

Here's what I try.

```
DateTime peopleTime = new DateTime();
```

Then I try to loop through the rows and add the time column.

```
peopleTime.Add(dataGrid.Rows[i].Cell[1].Value.ToString());
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have access to the rest of your code, but I don't think you can do math with string's. Do not cast time to string.

Comment: What exactly do you think the sum of a set of DateTimes would represent?

Comment: Also, have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.dateadd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` represents a point in time, you seem to want a duration, for that there's built in `TimeSpan` type.

A simple example how to parse and add up an array of string times, could look like this:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WDkRfo

```
var stringTimes = new [] { "01:30", "02:30" };
        
var total = new TimeSpan();
foreach(var stringTime in stringTimes) {
    total += TimeSpan.Parse(stringTime);
}
        
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Comment: Seems a better answer for explaining why the .Add method need a `TimeSpan` type and adding the string type.

Answer (score 3):

Is this that you want?

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse("18:30");
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse("00:40:00");
DateTime date3 = date1.Add(date2.TimeOfDay); 
Console.WriteLine(date3.TimeOfDay); // 19:10:00
```

Comment: The OP says: _I want to total up the time_ so what is the result of your code if instead of 40 minutes you add 5 hours and 30 minutes?

Comment: My output is 19:10:00 as I wrote in comment code. If sum that you said the result will be 00:00:00. You can run it here. https://dotnetfiddle.net/gOiVXX